# Drag and drop in WP7 for silverlight

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, drag-and-drop

I would like to have a way to drag some images that are displayed on my silvelight phone page to a specific location (for example a rectangle) on the same page.

How can I do this ?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: how are you displaying the imageS? In that they are plural how are you fitting them and teh drop target on the page? What have you tried?

Comment: The images are displayed in a list, throught databinding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at [Laurent Bugnon WP7 Multitouch Behavior](http://www.galasoft.ch/touch/wp7/). It's an easy to use `Behavior` and it manages Drag and Drop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tryed this behavior and I can "translate" an image. I can get the manipulation completed event, but how can I know the position of the image ? And look if it's inside a border component ?